# Linux "passwd" command can not force expire the password for the LDAP

Tags: linux, ldap, passwd

I have basic of setup of LDAP. Users can log and change of their password (`passwd user_name`) but when I am trying force expire the password: `password -e uesr_name` I can not do it. I got the error: does not exist in `/etc/passwd`. Where is the problem and how I can solved it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is crossposted: https://superuser.com/questions/1737843/linux-passwd-command-can-not-force-expire-the-password-for-the-ldap

Comment: AFAIK the problem can have several aspects: - there is no universal password expiration implementation in LDAP. So passwd doesn't know what to do and falls back to the default , changing `/etc/passwd` - admin privileges (root) on a Linux server don't translate automatically to full administrator rights in the LDAP server. Without those you can only change your own account properties and not those of another user. - It may depend on how you implemented LDAP integration. - you may need to set expiration via the appropriate tools that manage your LDAP directory.